# Use lapply to create new variable over multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, lapply

I have searched all the ***lapply*** questions and solutions, and none of those solutions seems to address and/or work for the following...

I have a list "temp" that contains the names of 100 data frames: "sim_rep1.dat" through "sim_rep100.dat".

Each data frame has 2000 observations and the same 11 variables: ARAND and w1-w10, all of which are numeric.

For all 100 data frames, I am trying to create a new variable called "ps_true" that incorporates certain of the "w" variables, each with a unique coefficient.

The only use of lapply that is working for me is the following:

```
lapply(mget(paste0("sim_rep", 1:100,".dat")), transform, 
            ps_true = (1 + exp(-(0.8*w1 - 0.25*w2 + 0.6*w3 - 
                       0.4*w4 - 0.8*w5 - 0.5*w6  + 0.7*w7)))^-1)
```

When I run the code above, R loops through all 100 data frames and shows newly calculated values for ps_true in the console. Unfortunately, the new column is not getting added to the data frames.

When I try to create a function, the wheels come completely off.

I have tried different variations of the following:

```
 lapply(temp, function(x){       
        ps_true = (1 + exp(-(0.8*w1 - 0.25*w2 + 0.6*w3 - 
                       0.4*w4 - 0.8*w5 - 0.5*w6  + 0.7*w7)))^-1
   cbind(x, ps_true)
   return(x)
 })
```

- *Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'w1' not found* results from the function shown above
- *Error in x$w1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors* results if I try to reference x$w1 instead
- *Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'w1' not found* results if I try to reference x[[w1]] instead
- *Error in x[["w1"]] : subscript out of bounds* results if I try to reference x[["w1"]] instead

I am hoping there is something obvious that I am missing. I'd appreciate your insights and suggestions to solve this frustrating problem.

***In response to Uwe's addendum:***

The code I had used to read all the files was the following:

```
temp = list.files(pattern='*.dat')
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
    assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i], header=F,sep="",
           col.names = c("ARAND", "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7", "w8", "w9", "w10")))
}
```

Comment: I've expanded [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775124/3817004) to cover the case all data.frames are stored in separate files on disk. The proposed approach will read all files at once into one large data.table.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I have edited my original question and included this code at the bottom. Thanks again, Uwe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the OP, there are 100 data.frames with identical columns names. The OP wants to create a new column in all of the data.frames using exactly the same formula.

This indicates a fundamental flaw in the design of the data structure. I guess, no data base admin would create 100 identical tables where only the data contents differs. Instead, he would create *one* table with an additional column identifying the origin of each row. Then, all subsequent operations would be applied on one table instead to be repeated for each of many.

In R, the `data.table` package has the convenient `rbindlist()` function which can be used for this purpose:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# get list of data.frames from the given names and
# combine the rows of all data sets into one large data.table
DT <- rbindlist(mget(temp), idcol = "origin")
# now create new column for all rows across all data sets
DT[, ps_true := (1 + exp(-(0.8*w1 - 0.25*w2 + 0.6*w3 - 
                            0.4*w4 - 0.8*w5 - 0.5*w6  + 0.7*w7)))^-1]
DT
```

> ```
>                 origin ARAND   w1   w2   w3   w4   w5   w6   w7   w8   w9  w10   ps_true
>      1:   sim_rep1.dat  -0.6 -0.5  0.2 -0.7  0.5  2.4 -0.2 -0.9 -1.1  0.3 -0.8 0.0287485
>      2:   sim_rep1.dat  -0.2  0.2  0.7  1.0  1.8 -0.2  0.8  0.3 -1.3 -1.6 -0.2 0.4588433
>      3:   sim_rep1.dat   1.6 -0.5  0.7 -0.7 -1.7  0.9 -1.2 -1.0  1.1 -0.3 -2.1 0.2432395
>      4:   sim_rep1.dat   0.1  1.2 -1.3 -0.1  0.3 -0.6  0.4  0.3  0.8 -1.2 -1.7 0.8313184
>      5:   sim_rep1.dat   0.1  0.2 -2.0  0.6 -0.3  0.2  0.2  0.5 -0.9 -0.8 -1.1 0.7738186
>     ---                                                                                 
> 199996: sim_rep100.dat   0.1 -1.4  1.6 -0.7 -1.0 -0.6  0.8 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.8 0.1323889
> 199997: sim_rep100.dat   0.3  1.3 -2.4 -0.7 -0.4  0.0  1.0 -0.2  1.0 -0.1  0.3 0.6769959
> 199998: sim_rep100.dat   0.3  1.2  0.0 -1.3 -0.8 -0.7 -0.3  0.1  0.9  0.9 -1.3 0.7824498
> 199999: sim_rep100.dat   0.5 -0.7  0.2  0.5  1.1 -0.3  0.3 -0.5 -0.8  1.9 -0.7 0.2669799
> 200000: sim_rep100.dat  -0.5  1.1  0.8  0.2 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4  1.1 -1.8  0.9 -1.3 0.9175867
> ```

`DT` consists now of 200 K rows. Performance is no reason to worry as `data.table`was built to deal with large (even larger) data efficiently.

---

The origin of each row can be identified in case the data of the individual data sets need to be treated separately. E.g.,

```
DT[origin == "sim_rep47.dat"]
```

> ```
>              origin ARAND   w1   w2   w3   w4   w5   w6   w7   w8   w9  w10   ps_true
>    1: sim_rep47.dat  -0.6 -0.5  0.2 -0.7  0.5  2.4 -0.2 -0.9 -1.1  0.3 -0.8 0.0287485
>    2: sim_rep47.dat  -0.2  0.2  0.7  1.0  1.8 -0.2  0.8  0.3 -1.3 -1.6 -0.2 0.4588433
>    3: sim_rep47.dat   1.6 -0.5  0.7 -0.7 -1.7  0.9 -1.2 -1.0  1.1 -0.3 -2.1 0.2432395
>    4: sim_rep47.dat   0.1  1.2 -1.3 -0.1  0.3 -0.6  0.4  0.3  0.8 -1.2 -1.7 0.8313184
>    5: sim_rep47.dat   0.1  0.2 -2.0  0.6 -0.3  0.2  0.2  0.5 -0.9 -0.8 -1.1 0.7738186
>   ---                                                                                
> 1996: sim_rep47.dat   0.1 -1.4  1.6 -0.7 -1.0 -0.6  0.8 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.8 0.1323889
> 1997: sim_rep47.dat   0.3  1.3 -2.4 -0.7 -0.4  0.0  1.0 -0.2  1.0 -0.1  0.3 0.6769959
> 1998: sim_rep47.dat   0.3  1.2  0.0 -1.3 -0.8 -0.7 -0.3  0.1  0.9  0.9 -1.3 0.7824498
> 1999: sim_rep47.dat   0.5 -0.7  0.2  0.5  1.1 -0.3  0.3 -0.5 -0.8  1.9 -0.7 0.2669799
> 2000: sim_rep47.dat  -0.5  1.1  0.8  0.2 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4  1.1 -1.8  0.9 -1.3 0.9175867
> ```

extracts all row belonging to data set `sim_rep47.dat`.

#### Data

For test and demonstration, I've created 100 sample data.frames using the code below:

```
# create vector of file names
temp <- paste0("sim_rep", 1:100, ".dat")
# create one sample data.frame
nr <- 2000L
nc <- 11L
set.seed(123L)
foo <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(nr * nc), 1), nrow = nr))
names(foo) <- c("ARAND", paste0("w", 1:10))
str(foo)
# create 100 individually named data.frames by "copying" foo
for (t in temp) assign(t, foo)
# print warning message on using assign
fortunes::fortune(236)
# verify objects have been created
ls()
```

---

#### Addendum: Reading all files at once

The OP has named the single data.frames `sim_rep1.dat`, `sim_rep2.dat`, etc. which resemble typical file names. Just in case the OP indeed has 100 files on disk I would like to suggest a way to read all files at once. Let's suppose all files are stored in one directory.

```
# path to data directory
data_dir <- file.path("path", "to", "data", "directory")
# create vector of file paths
files <- dir(data_dir, pattern = "sim_rep\\d+\\.dat", full.names = TRUE)
# read all files and create one large data.table
# NB: it might be necessary to add parameters to fread() 
# or to use another file reader depending on the file type
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), idcol = "origin")
# rename origin to contain the file names without path
DT[, origin := factor(origin, labels = basename(files))]
DT
```

> ```
>                origin ARAND   w1   w2   w3   w4   w5   w6   w7   w8   w9  w10   ps_true
>      1:  sim_rep1.dat  -0.6 -0.5  0.2 -0.7  0.5  2.4 -0.2 -0.9 -1.1  0.3 -0.8 0.0287485
>      2:  sim_rep1.dat  -0.2  0.2  0.7  1.0  1.8 -0.2  0.8  0.3 -1.3 -1.6 -0.2 0.4588433
>      3:  sim_rep1.dat   1.6 -0.5  0.7 -0.7 -1.7  0.9 -1.2 -1.0  1.1 -0.3 -2.1 0.2432395
>      4:  sim_rep1.dat   0.1  1.2 -1.3 -0.1  0.3 -0.6  0.4  0.3  0.8 -1.2 -1.7 0.8313184
>      5:  sim_rep1.dat   0.1  0.2 -2.0  0.6 -0.3  0.2  0.2  0.5 -0.9 -0.8 -1.1 0.7738186
>     ---                                                                                
> 199996: sim_rep99.dat   0.1 -1.4  1.6 -0.7 -1.0 -0.6  0.8 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.8 0.1323889
> 199997: sim_rep99.dat   0.3  1.3 -2.4 -0.7 -0.4  0.0  1.0 -0.2  1.0 -0.1  0.3 0.6769959
> 199998: sim_rep99.dat   0.3  1.2  0.0 -1.3 -0.8 -0.7 -0.3  0.1  0.9  0.9 -1.3 0.7824498
> 199999: sim_rep99.dat   0.5 -0.7  0.2  0.5  1.1 -0.3  0.3 -0.5 -0.8  1.9 -0.7 0.2669799
> 200000: sim_rep99.dat  -0.5  1.1  0.8  0.2 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4  1.1 -1.8  0.9 -1.3 0.9175867
> ```

All data sets are now stored in one large data.table `DT` consisting of 200 k rows. However, the order of data sets is different as `files` is sorted alphabetically, i.e.,

```
head(files)
```

> ```
> [1] "./data/sim_rep1.dat"   "./data/sim_rep10.dat"  "./data/sim_rep100.dat"
> [4] "./data/sim_rep11.dat"  "./data/sim_rep12.dat"  "./data/sim_rep13.dat"
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Uwe. Yes, the data sets need to be retained for additional analysis to be run separately. Your rbindlist solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

probably just need single brackets.

```
test = data.frame('w1' = c(1,2,3),'w2' = c(2,3,4))
temp = list(test,test,test)
temp2 = lapply(temp,function(x){cbind(x,setNames(x['w1'] + x['w2'],'ps_true'))})


temp2
[[1]]
   w1 w2 ps_true
1  1  2       3
2  2  3       5
3  3  4       7

[[2]]
   w1 w2 ps_true
1  1  2       3
2  2  3       5
3  3  4       7

[[3]]
   w1 w2 ps_true
1  1  2       3
2  2  3       5
3  3  4       7
```

Comment: When I type the same temp2 assignment using my temp list, I receive the following: _Error in x["w1"] + x["w2"] : non-numeric argument to binary operator_

Comment: If the above 3 lines work, its likely a data problem.  try the same code with temp[1:2] after you've checked that the first 2 data frames are fine in your temp

Comment: 'non-numeric argument to binary operator' typically occurs when the class of your data frame is non numeric

Comment: Thanks, hjw. I ended up using rbindlist. It allowed me to retain the info for my original data frames, but combine the data in one table. I appreciate your insight.